# Second Order Stochastic Dominance in terms of the pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The condition for the second-order stochastic dominance states that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^x F_X(t)-F_Y(t) \ge 0,
\end{align}
for all $x$.

My question: Can this condition be restated in terms of the pdf instead of the cdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate by parts and you will find that the integral is equal to
$$
\Bbb E[(x-X)^+-(x-Y)^+],
$$
where $b^+:=\max(b,0)$ denotes positive part. Written explicitly in terms of density functions this becomes
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-t)^+[f_X(t)-f_Y(t)]\,dt,
$$
which is the same as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^x (x-t)[f_X(t)-f_Y(t)]\,dt.
$$

Answer (score 0):

A well-known characterisation is that $X \sim f_X(x)$ second-order stochastically dominates $Y \sim g_Y(x)$ if 
$$\int u(x) f(x) dx \ge \int u(x) g(x) dx$$
for all concave (integrable) functions $u$.

Comment: Sure. But this is not really what I asked.

Comment: Agreed. And of course you also thought of writing $F_x$ as the integral of $f_x$ and state the condition using double integrals?